# Looking to add phpmailer library to Zend Framework setup

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpmailer

what is the best practice for adding and accessing libraries to ZF?  I'm trying to add phpmailer, should I just add it to the library folder?  How can I access this file now, as it does not use the ZF naming conventions.  Thanks!

Comment: Should those libraries be used by other applications on the same system as well or only by your application? Which OS are you using?

Comment: Hey hakre, thx for the response.  The library just needs to be used by my application, and i'm using windows vista, but why does OS matter?

Comment: OS can matter if OS provides a package with the library. Vista does not. I tend to suggest to add it into the library folder and include the file in your bootstrap, but you might want to consider to add it to the [autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html) as well. But I'm not a ZF pro with a quick example at hand.

Comment: I put all 3rd party libs in the library folder, and if possible use the Zend autoloader to load them or just reference them using `include realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/the_lib/script.php');`). Most of my projects rely on Propel, TCPDF and some company specific libs using this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution is to drop the PHPMailer class (and any other files) into your library folder.

<strike>As PHPMailer seems to use a filename convention that won't apply well to the autoloader (`class.phpmailer.php`), I'd just require the class file in your Bootstrap</strike>

You should then be able to create a new `PHPMailer` class anywhere in your app.

You could try and register an autoloader that would map the class name `PHPMailer` to `class.phpmailer.php` however IMO it's not worth the effort.

**UPDATE**

Come to think of it, I'd ignore the Bootstrap part and simply require the class when it's needed (say, in your controller). As the file is in your include path, all you would need is

```
require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';
$mailer = new PHPMailer;
```

Answer (score 4):

Drop the relevant files into the library folder. Then you could create an autoloader something like this:

In the file `library/My/Loader/Autoloader/PhpMailer.php`:

```
class My_Loader_Autoloader_PhpMailer implements Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Interface
{
    /**
     * Autoload a class
     *
     * @param   string $class
     * @return  mixed
     *          False [if unable to load $class]
     *          $class [if $class is successfully loaded]
     */
    public function autoload($class)
    {
        if ('PHPMailer' === $class) {
            include 'class.phpmailer.php';
            return $class;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then add this autoloader to the ZF autoloader stack, probably in `Bootstrap`:

```
protected function _initAutoloader()
{
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    // The following is not necessary if My_ is already a registered namespace 
    // in the ZF autoloader
    require 'My/Loader/Autoloader/PhpMailer.php'; 
    $autoloader->pushAutoloader(new My_Loader_Autoloader_PhpMailer());
}
```

I've done something like this for examples with more involved legacy class naming/mapping and it's been quite helpful.

Comment: So you're requiring two classes (autoloader and PHPMailer) to load one class? For the single-class PHPMailer library, I don't think it's worth the effort. Still, +1 for a fine answer

Comment: @Phil: Right, though this autoloader class is pretty small, so it saves having to load the larger PHPmailer class on those requests where it is not used. On the other hand, there is the extra overhead on the autoloader. Like you said, probably not worth the effort in this case; mostly trying to demonstrate the technique. Thanks for the upvote. Cheers! ;-)